# How can I use a background image on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I found this code

```
http://jsfiddle.net/dtrooper/AceJJ/
```

and I'm trying to add a background image to the canvas (so it won't be black).

I've added these lines to the $(document).ready function

```
var background = new Image();
background.src = url("img/header.jpg");
```

But all I get is **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**

I also want to have text on top of the background (saying something like "Welcome to the new year" + NewLine + "Be safe and good luck"

Thank You

Comment: Why do you call `url`? Did you define that function?

Comment: so i can set the background image

Comment: Where did you define the function `url`? Please show the complete code. The code you show in the question are not in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Why not just: `background.src = "img/header.jpg"`?

Comment: You could also just set an image as the background image using CSS or the `style` property.

Comment: the canvas is generated dynamically. so if I use css, how will the StyleSheet know that the object is present?

Comment: As @atornblad said, by using the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) directly on the DOM element. Or use a stylesheet with a selector that applies to the `canvas` element wherever it is added.

Comment: Or just give it an `id` or a `class` and set the style properties in a style sheet for a matching selector.

Comment: @softwareisfun  Having a quick play, I got this: http://jsfiddle.net/AceJJ/1741/ but you lose the effect of the trails - unless you add some opacity: http://jsfiddle.net/AceJJ/1747/ but then you loose the quality of the image

Answer (score 4):

In the loop function change this:

```
// clear canvas
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
context.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

To this:

```
context.save();
if (first) { // only the first time you draw the full image
  first = false;
  context.globalAlpha = 1;
} else {
    context.globalAlpha = 0.2; // <--- PLAY WITH THIS FOR BETTER EFFECT
}
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
context.restore()


// clear canvas
//context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
//context.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

And out of the loop function add this:

```
var img = new Image();
var first = true;
img.src = "YOUR_IMAGE_URL";
```

Is not perfect, but from here you can find your solution.

The example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AceJJ/1748/

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/6ju8acro/1/

javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://imagesci.com/img/2013/03/cute-christmas-dogs-8313-hd-wallpapers.jpg";

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.font = '40pt Calibri';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillText("Welcome to the new year", 250, 100);
  ctx.fillText("Be safe and good luck", 350, 600);
}
```

You have to create a new `Image` variable and then access its property `src` which is the source of the image. So you first create a new `Image` provide a source. Then we must first wait for the image to load. Once the image has loaded we render it to the canvas via `drawImage`, then we go ahead and draw some text using the `fillText` function.

You will have to work out how to centre the text correctly and change the image but the code I have provided should get you started :)

### Updated

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/AceJJ/1743/

```
// clear canvas
// Render background and text first
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
context.font = '40pt Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillText("Welcome to the new year", 150, 100);
context.fillText("Be safe and good luck", 250, 600);
//context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
//context.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

Just render the image and text in the loop function, however as I stated above you will need to work out the best way to render the image and text

### Another Update

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/AceJJ/1756/

To draw the firework trails over the image, just create particles when the rocket is rendered like so

```
  // ... near the end of the Rocket.prototype.render function
  c.fill();
  c.restore();

  var particle = new Particle(this.pos);

  particle.size = 10;

  particle.gravity = 0.2;
  particle.resistance = 0.92;
  particle.shrink = Math.random() * 0.05 + 0.93;

  particle.flick = true;
  particle.color = this.explosionColor;

  particles.push(particle);
};
```

Comment: after adding this, the image and text fades to black and the fireworks pop on a black background

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://imgurl.com";
```

url() is used in CSS.

Comment: when i place this inside document.ready, the image fades to black